# Loading images from four-square in to a gallery adapter

Tags: android

Hi am creating an application which pulls resources from Foursquare and displays it on the android phone and am having problems with loading images. The app runs but for some reason it does not load on the phone it only shows me the loader image which I defined

My code are as follows:

```
public class PicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //use the default gallery background image
    int defaultItemBackground;

    //gallery context
    private Context galleryContext;

    //array to store bitmaps to display
    private Bitmap[] imageBitmaps;
    //placeholder bitmap for empty spaces in gallery
    Bitmap placeholder;

    //constructor
    public PicAdapter(Context c) {

        //instantiate context
        galleryContext = c;

        //create bitmap array
        //imageBitmaps  = new Bitmap[10];
        //decode the placeholder image
        //placeholder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    }

    //BaseAdapter methods

    //return number of data items i.e. bitmap images
    public int getCount() {
        return PicturesURLlist.size();
    }

    //return item at specified position
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //return item ID at specified position
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //get view specifies layout and display options for each thumbnail in the gallery
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //create the view
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(galleryContext);
        //specify the bitmap at this position in the array
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmaps[position]);
        ImageLoader imgloader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

        int loader = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

        song = PicturesURLlist.get(position);
        //Log.d("Links", song.get(picurl));

        imgloader.DisplayImage(song.get(picurl), loader, imageView );
        //imageView.setImageBitmap((imgloader.DisplayImage(song.get(picurl), loader, imageView)));
        //set layout options
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(400, 600));
        //scale type within view area
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        //set default gallery item background
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(defaultItemBackground);
        //return the view
        return imageView;
    }

    //custom methods for this app

    //helper method to add a bitmap to the gallery when the user chooses one

}
```

My imagloader class

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService; 

public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
public String DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
{
    stub_id = loader;
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    Log.d("Image loader succes", url);
    if(bitmap!=null){
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Log.d("Image loader succes", "true");
    }
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(loader);
        Log.d("Image loader succes", "false");
    }
    return null;
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u;
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

Comment: is your adpater in scrollview?

Comment: You can try load fixed link to simple imageview to test your imageloaderr is working find. With your information, it's hard to figure it out with it doesn't load.

Comment: @AndroidLearner its a gallery adapter.

Comment: @Yul i did try and it works fine..

Comment: What does this line mean `imageView.setBackgroundResource(defaultItemBackground);`? And it does not load or you got force close?

Comment: @Yul it set the background image or colour to the activities's defualt

Comment: @PrincewillObinnaIwuorie Are you sure you are able to get that images from the specified url? Any internet problem?

Comment: @Appu yes am sure i tried with horizontal list view and the images displayed but i need to use gallery because of its snap feature

Comment: Okay. Where are you initializing this defaultItemBackground variable?

Comment: yeah but after i commented the line it did not still work